# Хранение данных пользователей сайта

Tags: база-данных, сессия, mysql

Пробую писать свою онлайн-игру (php, js, html), вот как хочу организовать данные:

На клиенте: **объект js** (как хранилище **всех данными игрока** - инициализируемый при входе в игру).

Сервер: **бд MySQL**(как постоянное хранилище) и **$_SESSION['xxx']** (как временное хранилище **всех данных игрока** - инициализируемый при при его отсутствии).

Вопрос 1: даст ли это преимущество скорости и производительности (может, я что-то не учёл)?

P.S. Как я к этому пришёл? Задавался вопросом, зачем искать (выборка бд) координаты города (любые данные игрока) среди всех игроков, если можно организовать такую структуру:

```
бд(

игрок1(город(название,координаты), воины(тип, кол-во)),

игрок2(город(название,координаты), воины(тип, кол-во))

)
```

**Т.е. та же MySQL, только для каждого игрока своя БД/таблица.**

Вопрос 2: существуют ли базы данных с подобной структурой?

**Обновление**

Может, так будет понятней:

1. Запрос (любой) от клиента (AJAX).
2. Если `$_SESSION['player']`(все данные, касающиеся игрока) существует -> берём оттуда, если нет -> берём из БД и записываем в сессию.
3. Обрабатываем данные.
4. Ответ.

Comment: что то я совсем ничего не понял(

Comment: Может быть, все-таки воины?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Пишите, как пишется. Оптимизировать будете, когда будет опыт и возникнет проблема.

Comment: @Равнодушный "Пишите, как пишется" это в корне неправильно...

Comment: @rooty, ну, важно не столько само действие, сколько отношение к нему. Если "пишите, как пишется", и при этом анализируете то, что написали, ищите возможные улучшения/решения, то разве это будет плохо? Не писать в данном случае будет еще хуже. Опыт-то никто не отменял.

Comment: "анализируете то, что написали" и "пишите, как пишется" это взаимоисключающие понятия... либо то, либо другое...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Вопрос 1: Даст ли это преимущество скорости и производительности

Преимущество по сравнению с чем? Хрустальный шар подсказывает, что может, по сравнению с простым хранением пользовательских данных в MySQL — тогда это зависит от того, [какой обработчик сохраняет сессии](http://php.net/manual/ru/session.customhandler.php). Если тот, что по умолчанию, файловый — может быть и так, что БД будет быстрее за счет кэширования.

> Вопрос 2: существуют ли Базы Данных с подобной структурой?

См. [NoSQL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) – вам ведь требуется хранить пары ключ-значение: user_id - json_data.

Чтобы далеко не бегать, я бы посоветовал [Redis](http://redis.io/): он невероятно быст, т.к. держит данные в операвтивной памяти, плюс сохраняет все на диск.

Answer (score 2):

Эмъ... перед тем как писать какую-то игру, лучше бы познакомиться с основами.

Какое к черту "для каждого игрока своя БД/таблица"??? Один игрок - одна запись в таблице.

Судя по вашим вопросам, вы либо упретесь не в БД/сессии, а в плохо написанный код, либо ваша игра никогда не наберет столько игроков, чтобы вы заметили какие-либо тормоза.

Как вариант - писать игру ради изучения этих самых основ. Т.е. не ставить цель "завоевать мир", не писать, "чтобы быстрее работало", а писать, чтобы понять, что и как работает, постепенно углубляясь в детали. Тогда многие вопросы отпадут сами собой.

Comment: Правильно! В вашем случае надо три таблицы:
1. Игроки(вся информация по игроку)
2. Города(название города, координаты)
3. Воины

Сделать связку таблиц и просто добавлять/обновлять записи в БД.
Так будет куда быстрее работать, чем для каждого пользователя хранить по таблице - да и это полный бред.